# How to reset a setTimeout function in a button so it can run again

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, jquery-timing

There is a button that its function runs couple of setTimeout functions that they all run one by one. so I want to reset the setTimeout so if I press the button again, the whole process happens again.

How can I do it?

My example code:

```
function add(){

setTimeout(function() {

    $(".line1").fadeIn(function(){
    $(".lineBox").animate({width: "260px"}, 
        function(){
            $(".line2").fadeIn();
            $(".text1").delay(250).fadeIn();                
        });
    });

}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
   $(".heyyyyy").append("y");
}, 3000);
```

}

HTML::

```
<div onclick="add()"></div>
```

So how can I reset this setTimeout so if I run the add() function, it runs again ?

Comment: To cancel a timeout:
`var timerId = window.setTimeout(...)` => `window.clearTimeout(timerId)`.
This will only stop the timer before your animations start. I don't know the way to cancel your animations

Answer (score 2):

To control `setTimeouut` assign to it a global variable:

```
var cid = setTimeout(...);
```

When you need to reset it, call `clearTimout` first then `setTimeout`

```
clearTimeout( cid );
cid = setTimeout( ... ); //you must reassign it to same var if you plan to reset again.
```

**Note** `setTimeout` runs only once. Checkout `setInterval` if you're looking to run some code every few seconds.